# How can I set a Steam achievement in Steam via LibGDX or native Java?

Tags: java, libgdx, steam

Is it possible to set or 'unlock' a Steam achievement via LibGDX or with a native Java solution?

If so, how it this possible. Furthermore, what would be a good implementation for 'saving' achieved achievements when you were offline. For example, when I enable the airsafe mode on my laptop and then run the game, be really good at it and unlock an achievement, how can it be saved the next time I have WiFi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Steamworks is a C++ API, you'd need to write a wrapper. You can use the [Java Native Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) (JNI) for this, or possible the [Java Native Access](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access) API instead. The JNI is the "classical" method, the JNA thing seems to be newer and I know less about it.

The Steamworks SDK is not public, so I can't link you directly to the interface you'd want to wrap, but all the ones you'd want to wrap are probably located in `ISteamUserStats.h`.

Fortunately, Steamworks is so popular that there are already wrappers other people have written for you, such as [steamworks4j](https://github.com/code-disaster/steamworks4j).

Steamworks services support an offline mode themselves, so you should not *need* to do anything specific yourself to deal with tracking and recording achievements when the user is offline.